# How to improve performance by saving results of queries in tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm working with a very large database and we want to display it's data using an online data visualization software. My problem is that the DB is so big I can't get a specific query to run in less than 30 seconds. This makes the experience of visualizing the data very poor and so I need to find a way to execute my queries faster.

I've been evaluating running a maintenance plan that runs a procedure that selects this query into a table every 30 minutes or so. I'm wondering whether this is a good approach or if I can optimize my query further.

I'm adding the query below:

```
SELECT
    CY.CycleGroupName AS CycleName,
    FF.WBSCode, 
    CC.CostCenterCode,
    CC.Name AS CostCenterName,
    IIF(FF.ClientSpecific = 'Overhead', CC.GlobalLocal, 'Local') AS GlobalLocal, 
    PC.ProfitCenterCode,
    PC.Name AS ProfitCenterName,
    FN.ForecastNodeCode AS ForecastNodeCode,
    FN.Name AS ForecastNodeName,
    FN.GSGeographicUnit,
    FN.GSCountry,
    FN.Domain,
    FN.Location,
    CO.Name AS CountryName,
    CO.Classification AS CountryClassification,
    GU.Name AS GeographicUnitName,
    GU.GeographicAreaCode,
    ReportLine2,
    ReportLine3,
    ReportLine4,
    IIF(RL.IsGrossCost = 'Yes', 'Gross Cost', '') AS GrossCostClassification,
    ProductivityCategory,
    FF.ClientSpecific,
    FF.ResourceID,
    FF.CurrencyType,
    CO.CurrencyCode AS LocalCurrencyCode, 
    FF.InputCurrencyCode AS InputCurrencyCode, 
    FF.Comments,
    FF.FiscalMonthNumber,
    FF.Amount * Multiplier AS Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CQ.CycleName,
        FF.TemplateID,
        FF.HeadcountID,
        FF.BorrowedID,
        CT.CurrencyType, 
        FF.WBSCode,
        FF.CostCenterCode,
        FF.ProfitCenterCode,
        FF.ForecastNodeCode,
        FF.CountryCode,
        FF.ReportLine,
        FF.CostElementCode,
        'T' + CAST(FF.TemplateID AS NVARCHAR) + 'H' + IIF(FF.HeadcountID IS NOT NULL, 'H' + CAST(FF.HeadcountID AS NVARCHAR), 'B' + CAST(FF.BorrowedID AS NVARCHAR)) AS ResourceID,
        FF.InputCurrencyCode,
        FF.ProductivityCategory,
        FF.ClientSpecific,
        FF.Comments,
        FF.FiscalMonthNumber,
        IIF(CT.Number = 30, FF.Amount * FX.Sep, FF.Amount) AS Amount
    FROM dbo.FinancialsForecast FF
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CyclesQuarters CQ ON FF.QuarterCode = CQ.QuarterCode
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CurrencyTypes CT ON 1 = 1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CostCenters CC ON FF.CostCenterCode = CC.CostCenterCode 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Countries CO ON ISNULL(CC.CountryCode, FF.CountryCode) = CO.CountryCode
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FXRates FX ON CO.CurrencyCode = FX.CurrencyCode AND FF.Year = FX.Year AND FF.QuarterCode = FX.QuarterCode
    WHERE
        CQ.CycleName IS NOT NULL
        AND FiscalMonthNumber > CQ.LastActualsMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ISNULL(CQ.CycleName, 'Previous Actuals') AS CycleName,
        NULL AS TemplateID,
        NULL AS HeadcountID,
        NULL AS BorrowedID,
        FA.CurrencyType, 
        FA.WBSCode,
        FA.CostCenterCode,
        FA.ProfitCenterCode,
        NULL AS ForecastNodeCode,
        FA.CountryCode,
        NULL AS ReportLine,
        FA.CostElementCode,
        NULL AS ResourceID,
        NULL AS InputCurrencyCode,
        ProductivityCategory,
        FA.ClientSpecific,
        NULL AS Comments,
        FA.FiscalMonthNumber,
        FA.Amount
    FROM dbo.FinancialsActuals FA
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CyclesQuarters CQ ON FA.Year = (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Settings WHERE Name = 'CurrentYear')
        LEFT JOIN dbo.WBS W ON FA.WBSCode = W.WBSCode
        LEFT JOIN dbo.BusinessActivitiesLevel1 B1 ON W.BusinessActivityLevel1Code = B1.BusinessActivityLevelCode
    WHERE
        FA.Year >= (SELECT CAST(Value AS INT) FROM dbo.Settings WHERE Name = 'CurrentYear') - 1
        AND FiscalMonthNumber <= ISNULL(CQ.LastActualsMonth, 12)
) FF
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CostCenters CC ON FF.CostCenterCode = CC.CostCenterCode
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Countries CO ON ISNULL(CC.CountryCode, FF.CountryCode) = CO.CountryCode
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProfitCenters PC ON CC.ProfitCenterCode = PC.ProfitCenterCode 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ForecastNodes FN ON ISNULL(ISNULL(CC.ForecastNodeCode, FF.ForecastNodeCode), PC.ForecastNodeCode) = FN.ForecastNodeCode 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.GeographicUnits AS GU ON CO.GeographicUnitCode = GU.GeographicUnitCode 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CostElements CE ON FF.CostElementCode = CE.CostElementCode
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportLines RL ON ISNULL(CE.ReportLine, FF.ReportLine) = RL.ReportLine AND RL.Number = 4
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportLinesLevels RLL ON RL.ReportLine = RLL.ReportLine4
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CyclesGroups CY ON FF.CycleName = CY.CycleName
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post the original query and table definition etc to see if we can help optimize the query. At this point the best anybody can do it guess because don't have any actual details.

Comment: Did you really optimize the query in every possible way?

Comment: if possible, maybe you should consider implementing paging

Comment: I just edited the question to add the query, all tables used have a primary key instead of the FinancialsActuals table. Also I have added indexes when necessary. I have considered indexing the table itself but as it uses many tables in my DB and returns even more rows that the original tables I'm afraid the performance gain wouldn't be much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Running a 30+ second query every 30 minutes on the surface seems reasonable.  However, it introduces all sorts of problems.  In particular, a user might reload data and see things change -- sometimes.  A discontinuous user experience is usually a bad thing.  And, a background load of roughly 2% might affect other the performance of other queries.

My reaction is:  Only do this as a last resort.  Databases have multiple options for improving performance -- indexes, partitioning, improved SQL, SSD disks (for instance).  The application itself could create a temporary table.  Although this eats up 30 seconds initially, subsequent use of the table should be fast.

Comment: thank you Gordon, as requested I added the details of the query in the question.